# Selenium VBA - Won't tick tickbox

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium

I have a spreadsheet that is scraping some data off a website.

One part of my program is to tick a tickbox.
I'm able to find the element without any problem using FindElementbyCSS but clicking it doesn't tick the tick box.

this is my code

```
.FindElementByCss("label[for='chkStdDev1']").Click
```

This is the tickbox (the first one, second one is ticked by default)

[image]

and this is what I see when I inspect the element

[image]

Was nice and happy when I managed to find the element correctly, but now it's driving me a bit insane as it won't tick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to check the label rather than the checkbox type input.

Use

```
.FindElementById("chkStdDev1").Click
```